# How can I declare variables in R such that I can use them in a graph plot for different observations?

Tags: r

I have a question regarding R. Please help. This is for an assignment.

I have a dataset of school students and their marks in various subjects in various exams over the year in exams. I have plotted individual student's marks in each exam over the year using ggplot2.
There are nearly a 1000 students. I cannot run the plot commands for each student individually by changing the input observation in every place in the code.

How can I declare variables for class and student name in R such that I can call upon the class and student name for whichever specific student I want to get a graph of. Thus I won't have to replace the values every time I need to run the code for a different student.

[this is a snapshot of the data](https://i.stack.imgur.com/tilOu.png)

[image]

```
require(ggplot2)  
Exam <- factor(c1$Performance,level=c("Name","Test 1 Percentage","Test 2 Percentage","Half Yearly Exam Percentage","Test 3 Percentage","Test 4 Percentage","Final Exam Percentage")) 
plot1 <- ggplot(c1,aes(x=Exam,group=1)) + 
         geom_line(aes(x=Exam,y=`Aarna Patel`,colour="Aarna Patel")) + geom_point(aes(x=Exam,y=`Aarna Patel`,text=paste("Aarna Patel:",`Aarna Patel`),colour="Aarna Patel")) +
         geom_line(aes(x=Exam,y=`Class Average`,colour="Class Average")) +geom_point(aes(x=Exam,y=`Class Average`,text=paste("Class Average:",`Class Average`),
         colour="Class Average")) + ylim(0,100) + xlab("Exam") +ylab("Percentage") + ggtitle("Performance Graph") 
require(plotly) 
ggplotly(plot1,tooltip="text") %>% config(displayModeBar = F)
```

I need to define variable for class1 and 'Aarna Patel' such that I can change class and name without replacing these values everywhere in the code.

Thank You for your help in advance.

Comment: See `help("aes_")`, in particular the examples. And a warning for free: Don't pass `Exam` as a separate vector. Put it into the data.frame. Otherwise, there is no guarantee that `ggplot2` will keep the same order for both the vector and the data.frame.

Comment: @Roland Thank you sir. I took your advice and put the Exam in my data frame.